# Django: can't add image from site, but it works from Django Administration page

Tags: python, html, django

I try add image from form, on site. My forms work trough, django administration site perfectly. But on site, when I press submit button, page are reload, and I get the information that I need to add image again. All informations, after I reload page,  stay as the was, but added image disappear.

models.py

```
class UrlUpload(models.Model):
    """docstring for """
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='/home/mariusz/web/moje/moje/static/covers/')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    description = models.TextField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import UrlUpload
class UrlUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UrlUpload
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'category','photo']
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UrlUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_files(request.FILES['/covers/'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('profile.html') #dodac potem strone potwierdzjaca wyslanie
    else:
        form = UrlUploadForm()
    return render_to_response('profile.html', {'form': form}, RequestContext(request))
```

profile.html

```
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class="panel-title">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-film"></i>
                            <h4>Dodaj Informacje</h4>
                            <form  method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
                            {{ form|crispy}}
                            <input class="btn btn-success" type='submit' value="Dodaj" />
                            </form>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Try adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your `<form>`.

Comment: I just add this a second a go. But still is not working.

Comment: are you getting any sort of response from the server? I'm wondering if this is related to folder permission problem.

Answer (score 0):

I change my views.py to

```
    @login_required
def profile(request):
    form = UrlUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    queryset = UrlUpload.objects.all()
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        print instance
    context = {
        "form" : form,
        "queryset": queryset

    }
    return render(request, "profile.html", context)
```

And it works right now.

Comment: it's a form to create an object or to update object already set?